# How do I annotate variables in an included PHP file?

Tags: php, netbeans, annotations

In my controller I have code like this:

```
public function showStudent($id)
{
    $student = new Student();
    $student->loadFromId($id);

    /* call the view */
    include '/path/to/student/view.php';
}
```

In the view.php file I want my code editor (netbeans, of course) to know $student is an instance of the Student class so it can suggest and check methods and properties etc. Can I help the editor to know this with an annotation, like

```
<?php
/**
* @magic Student $student
*/
?>
<html>
....
<p>Good day, <?= $student->name; ?></p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* @var $student Student */
$student->name;
```

---

Netbeans, of course? You should look at [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work for me. According to the ApiGen docs @var takes two arguments: datatype and description and should precede the variable declaration. I don't want to redeclare the variable

Comment: No dice. Maybe it's Sublime specific?

Comment: Your answer should work on a healthy netbeans install: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222012  Thanks for putting me on the right track.